# Flask vs Terminal: how do I manage imports so that I can use codes in both?

Tags: python-import

I have a Flask project with the following directory structure:

```
-my_project
    - flask_code.py
    - module
        - submodule
        - foo.py
        - bar.py
        - xyz.py
```

In flask_code.py, I must import both foo and bar. Therefore, flask_code has the following import statements:

```
"""flask_code.py"""
from module.foo import *
from module.bar import *
```

In foo.py, I need to import xyz. I also have implemented a main function in foo for testing, which I usually call from command line. If I write the imports of foo like this:

```
"""foo.py import 1"""
from module.xyz import *
```

The flask application runs exactly as expected. But, if I try to run foo.py from command line, I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module'

On the other hand, if I change the imports of foo to:

```
"""foo.py import 2"""
from xyz import *
```

the ModuleNotFoundError is not thrown anymore when foo.py is called from command line, which I guess it's expected. But, the flask application can't find module xyz on its own.

Both my_project and module folders have a init.py empty file.

I want to manage these imports so that I can both use the flask application and call the scripts from command line for testing. Thanks in advance!